# Get input from user and open popup on form submit

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I have this form

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="track-validate-detail">
           <input type="text" name="orderid" id="track"/>
           <button type="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I would like to get the orderid input from user and open the result in popup window

This is how magento popup works

```
<a class="askTrackBtn" href="javascript:;" onclick="popWin('<?php echo Mage::helper('shipping/data')->getTrackingPopUpUrlByOrderId($_order->getId()) ?>', 'tracking the order', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=600,resizable=yes');return false;"><span><?php echo $this->__('Track Order') ?></span></a>
```

Can someone help me to merge onclick code to form?

Please note `$_order->getId()` will be replaced by the input entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

when you will get order id in post from end user via form you can trigger click event by javascript and pass that particular order id from javascript function to other page.

for event you can use like below.

`event.simulate.js` fits your needs.

It allows you to manually trigger native events, such as click or hover like so:

```
$('askTrackBtn').simulate('click'); // give your id to anchor link
```

it will work just as if you would have clicked the element yourself.

For custom events you can use the standard prototype method `Event.fire().`

hope this will sure help you.

let me know if i can help you further.

Comment: @Giri, it is working at my end.i would be glad. if you will accept my answer and vote up. so some one can utilize if future if they have same requirement to do.